# Geocoding things from the database?

Tags: geocoding

I am kind of new to Geocoding.  What I want to do is pull a bunch of names of places from the DB, and display them as markers on the page.  And then allow people to choose different options which would force another db query, which would place a number of new markers on the page.

Is that possible?  It seems like relatively simple functionality, but since I am not good at JSON, it is giving me a hard time.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to geocode and really you need to give more information!

For example, in an offline environment, MapPoint is a pretty good solution (costs about $200/300 license). It can be made to work on a webserver but isn't usually worth the effort.

For a web server, then I would look at a web service. These are usually limited for free use, or pay for heavier (or commercial) use. Your question is too wide to give specifics, but look at the web services provided by Bing Maps, Google Maps, Yahoo (yes they're still around), and OpenStreetMaps-based.  bing Maps and Google Maps look like they'll be around for a long time - but might cost, depending on your application. OpenStreetMaps promises to have the widest coverage (including non NAm/EUR countries), but probably doesn't have the coverage of the others, yet.

Answer (score 0):

After figuring this out, I made a tool that takes an address and converts it to lat/lng.  It also has a code tutorial: http://comehike.com/utils/address_to_geolocation.php

I hope it helps people.  Would be fun to get feedback too :)